# Restructure code to avoid Angular Change Detection Infinite Loop

Tags: angular, angular5

My model has a one to many relationship between **Post** and **Img**s i.e. each Post has a number of **Img**s. One of the simplified ways of displaying this structure would be:

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
     {{post.postId}} 
      <p  *ngFor="let img of getImgs(post.postId)">{{img.url}}</p>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

My problem is that the page goes into an Infinite Loop due to Angular's Change Detection mechanism. Is there a better way to restructure this code? *(I'm using **Angular 5**)* A simplified version of my code is as below:

My AppComponent looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Post} from "./post"
import {PostService} from "./post.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Img} from "./img";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [PostService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  posts : Post[];
  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPosts();
  }

  getPosts(): void {
    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts);
  }

  getImgs(postId : string) : Img[] {
    var retImgs : Img[];
    this.postService.getImgsByPostId(postId).subscribe( imgs => retImgs = imgs);
    return retImgs;
  }
}
```

I get **Post**s and **Img**s from a Web Service. The **Post**s do not contain the **Img**s as part of themselves, but the **Img**s are retrieved using the **postId**. If I would like to keep this model where the **Img**s are not part of the **Post**s, I find it difficult to store the **Img**s in the `AppCompnent`. This forces me to put the `getImgs()` call in the HTML Template, which gets called on every Change Detection event. What is the normal way in Angular 5 to handle this scenario?

I can ofcourse do some hacks to save/cache the output of `getImgs()`, so I don't need to call the Web Service for subsequent requests or I could just change my model, but I am wondering how this is normally done.

Is there anyway to call a method from the Template such that it does not get called on every change detection mechanism?

---

**Edit**
In Response to @**Floor**s suggestion to use a smarter `getImgs()` that would cache the Images in a `Map` I have tried the following `AppComponent`: *(The Imports and the Component Decorator are as above)*

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  posts : Post[];
  postIdToImgs : Map<string, Img[]>;  //Added
  constructor(private postService: PostService) {
    this.postIdToImgs = new Map<string, Img[]>();  //Added
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPosts();
  }

  getPosts(): void {
    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts);
  }

  getImgs(postId : string) : Img[] {
    var retImgs : Img[];
    console.log(`Call to getImgs(${postId})`);  //Added
    if(this.postIdToImgs.has(postId)) {    //Added
      console.log('Found value in Cache');  //Added
      retImgs = this.postIdToImgs.get(postId);  //Added
      return retImgs; //Added
    }  //Added
    this.postService.getImgsByPostId(postId).subscribe( imgs => {
    this.postIdToImgs.set(postId, imgs); //Added
    retImgs = imgs;
});
    return retImgs;
  }
}
```

Yes, this stops calls to the Backend after the first iteration, but I still get an Infinite sequence of

> Cal to getImgs(#postId)
>   Found value in Cache

Where #postId is one of the 10 posts that I have on this page. I'm trying to learn Angular, so I'm not trying to just get this to work. I'm trying to find out:

> **Is there a way to have a method/function in the Template that is not called on every change detection?**

Comment: why dont you make get get images call inside the get posts call and add the images relevant to the posts to the post data structure?

Comment: Thank you **floor**. There are two problems: First, can someone confirm if there is no way to put a method in the HTML Template and have it not called on every change detection cycle. If this is true, then we cannot have methods in the HTML template because of performance reasons. Two, if I did what you suggest, I would have to change the Posts data structure, which I want to avoid. If this is the only way to go then I don't mind doing this.

Comment: there are many ways to solve this. you could make your getImgs call smarter, you could create a post component which takes a single post as a data structure and on ngInit get the images for that post. What exactly is the issue with your current code? Do you have many posts? because that would mean a getImg call per post. You could also get all posts and get all images and create a map of images and use the postID as the key.

Comment: I'm curious what you mean by making getImgs call smarter i.e. how would this look? If I keep this method in the Template it would keep getting called irrespective of whether or not I send out a request to the WebService.

Comment: you could keep a list of all post IDs used to make the getImgs call and only make the call if the postID isn't in the list. this would eliminate duplicate calls for the same images. you should also keep track of the images returned from the call and stash them in that list as well. A map would be best I guess make the postId the key and assign it the list of images. If that key exists on your map object don;t make the call and instead return the images on that key.

Comment: By looking at your code it doesn't look like it would create a constant loop. There must be something else causing the problem. Could you post more information. Do you get errors in the console? whats the network tab look like. What exactly happens on screen?

Comment: @floor - I have implemented your suggestion to use a Map to create a smarter `getImgs()` method and I have updated my post above, and I still get an infinite loop. Yes, it does not go to the backend, but it still calls the method forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move your code to a pipe, which is not called everytime change detection takes place

https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-pipes

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'getImages',

})
export class GetImagesPipe  implements PipeTransform {
   postIdToImgs : Map<string, Img[]> =  new Map<string, Img[]>();

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  transform(postId: string): any {


       var retImgs : Img[];
    console.log(`IN PIPE: Call to getImgs(${postId})`); 

    /*This commented cache implementation is not needed as the pipe won't be called again if the post does not change

      if(this.postIdToImgs.has(postId)) {   
      console.log('IN PIPE: Found value in Cache'); 
      retImgs = this.postIdToImgs.get(postId);  
      return retImgs; 
    } */ 
    this.postService.getImgsByPostId(postId).subscribe( imgs => {
    this.postIdToImgs.set(postId, imgs); //Added
    retImgs = imgs;
});
    return retImgs;
  }


}
```

I created a stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9n9h18?file=app%2Fimg.pipe.ts

Comment: Thank you **David**. I was unaware that pure pipes could be used here.  I liked this answer because it lets me keep my model. I do not like the fact that Angular requires you to write a pipe for every a trivial function/method that you would like to put in the Template. By the way, since the pipe is only called once, you do not need to cache the values in the `Map` i.e. you can leave out the added complexity, and it would still just call it once.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this problem is to put both object into a wrapper.
Fill this wrapper with both the post and it's belonging images.
And then perform ngFor using this wrapper.

e.g.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Post} from "./post"
import {PostService} from "./post.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Img} from "./img";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [PostService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  myWrapperList: Array<MyWrapper> = []; 

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.init();
  }

  init(): void {

    this.postService.getPosts().subscribe( posts => 

       posts.forEach(post => {
           this.postService.getImgsByPostId(post.postId).subscribe(imgs => 
             let myWrapper = new MyWrapper(post, imgs);
             this.myWrapperList.push(myWrapper);
       });

    );
  }

}


export class MyWrapper {
    constructor(
      public post: Post,
      public images: Array<Images>
    ){}
}
```

And in your template

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let wrapper of myWrapperList">
     {{wrapper?.post?.postId}} 
      <p  *ngFor="let img of wrapper.images">{{img?.url}}</p>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good solution. Can you comment on my question regarding if it were possible to have a method in the template that was not called by the change detection algorithm?

Comment: @DiabolicWords, you can simply posts.forEach(post => {
           this.postService.getImgsByPostId(post.postId).subscribe( imgs => post.images=imgs)})